# Why does data not load from NavLink click?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a NavLink pointed to a razor page. The link resolves correctly, but the page does not load data. If I simply refresh the page, things load correctly.

NavMenu. This builds the link correctly. https://localhost:7000/projecttasks/2

```
@foreach (var dsIe in DsIeService.DsIes)
        {
            <div class="nav-item px-2">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@($"projecttasks/{dsIe.Id}")">
                    @dsIe.Name
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        }
```

Page. The link is directed correctly to https://localhost:7000/projecttasks/2

```
@page "/projecttasks/{ieId:int}"
@inject IProjectTaskService ProjectTaskService
...
    [Parameter]
    public int ieId { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        await ProjectTaskService.GetProjectTasks(ieId);
        ProjectTaskService.ProjectTaskChanged += StateHasChanged;
     }
```

Client Service.

```
public async Task GetProjectTasks(int ieId)
        {
            var response = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>>($"api/projecttask/{ieId}");
            if (response is { Data: { } })
                ProjectTasks = response.Data;
            ProjectTaskChanged?.Invoke();
        }
```

Server Service.

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>> GetProjectTasksAsync(int ieId)
        {
            var projectTask = await _context.ProjectTasks
                .Include(d => d.DailyStatus)
                .Include(p => p.ProjectStatus)
                .Where(i => i.DsIeId == ieId)
                .OrderBy(f => f.FiNumber)
                .ThenBy(c => c.CaseNumber)
                .ToListAsync();

            return new ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>
            {
                Data = projectTask
            };
        }
```

Controller.

```
[HttpGet("{ieId}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<List<ProjectTask>>>> GetProjectTasks(int ieId)
        {
            var result = await _projectTaskService.GetProjectTasksAsync(ieId);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Comment: I changed my answer, have a look.. You don't want to subscribe to the event more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your Navlink goes to the same page with just a different parameter then OnInitialized is not called.

```cs
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
     ProjectTaskService.ProjectTaskChanged += StateHasChanged;
  }

  protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
  {
     await ProjectTaskService.GetProjectTasks(ieId);
  }
```